# How to get logged off users email address in meteor?

Tags: email, templates, meteor, iron-router

In my routing file I have the following down.

```
Router.route('/user/:createdBy', {
        name: 'user',
        /*onBeforeAction: function () {
         AccountsEntry.signInRequired(this);
         },*/
        fastRender: true,
        data: function () {
            paramId = this.params.createdBy;
            // Still have to find a way how to get data
            // Function below is only for signed in users
            return Meteor.users.findOne(paramId);
        }
});
```

In my user template I want to display the email. I have it like this `{{emails.[0].address}}` and as `{{users.emails.[0].address}}` but the email doesn't show up. It only shows up if the user is logged in. I however have the users Id as my param. (This is for testing purposes guys!).

Comment: What users are you publishing to a not-logged-in user? You could make a server publication that takes paramId as a parameter and returns that user (as a cursor) then subscribe to it in your route's `waitOn` section.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the logged off user information, you could try this:

```js
// in your router.js

// callback would be called when login is successful
Meteor.onLogin(function(){
  Session.set('login user', Meteor.user());
})

// in your template, or other functions
// the Session would be update only if a user login successfully
var userId = Session.get('login user')._id;
```

Click [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_onlogin) for more details.

I wish it could help :-)